# Integrating functions from other source codes in SCIP

Tags: c++, scip

I'm a master student and I'm currently using SCIP for my thesis. The main implementation task of my thesis is to integrate a meta-heuristic already coded in C++ and ready to be used in the SCIP branch-and-bound process to enhance the solution process of my problem.

How can I call the functions from the meta-heuristic files?

I'm not sure if this information can be useful but I'm using Matlab to load my data and then to compile and run SCIP in Visual Studio using MEX functions. I have already set all the necessary headers in SCIP and Matlab.

Comment: Why do you want to use MATLAB when your code is written in C++? I suppose, it would be easier to integrate your code into SCIP directly.

Comment: It's because of the data volume which is huge and Matlab can handle it effectively. But actually you're right, but I have to follow the house' rules :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you extend your SCIP by a primal heuristic plugin. General instructions about adding a primal heuristic can be found [here](http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/HEUR.php).
A C++ Example in source code may be the well-documented [TSP example](http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/TSP_MAIN.php).
In there, you can include and use your existing meta-heuristic code package.